# 2 computers, 1 with Ubuntu and a wireless problem

Tags: wireless

Okay so, there are 2 computers in my house (apartments), one desktop and one laptop (mine, the issue). The desktop is brand new, my fiancee uses it daily and it runs windows 8; mine is running ubuntu 12.04 LTS with gnome shell installed. The windows computer is plugged into the modem and gets it's internet from that, but my laptop gets it wirelessly, which is the problem. Here's a little back story: I had windows 7 installed not even 5 days ago and the wireless was working fine. The only time my laptop didn't have internet was when the other computer wasn't getting it either (which was rare). But after installing ubuntu (before and after tinkering (adding drivers, gnome shell, my apps, etc.)), it cuts in and out every few minutes; though it can last a while, it isn't predictable. I've looked up ways to fix it and none seem feasible to me, though it could just be my inexperience with this sort of thing. If specs are needed, I'm gonna need someone to tell me how, as that's how little I know about this. Any help would be appreciated at this point, I really don't want to go back to windows but right now it looks like it's the only option. I'll wait a while for replies but if I can't fix it soon I may need to stop trying to use ubuntu altogether. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I've noticed two things since posting this, one is that even when my computer is plugged in to the ethernet, my internet is still cutting out; and two is that when I'm online (I use google chrome) I get a error saying that there was a problem, that usually but doesn't always appear underneath my web browser window after it fails to connect to the DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue several times, mostly the problem is because you don't have the necessary drivers installed. Also, you may improve the connection speed by disabling IPv6.

**Disabling IPv6:**
Go to the Network menu and click on the "Connection Information" menu. If there's nothing under the IPv6 box, you can safely [disable IPv6](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html).

**Installing Wireless N drivers:**
If you use a Wireless N device (which may be the case), you should install the `wlan-ng` drivers (you can search them in the Software Center).

Comment: Alright! Thank you for your excellent help Alex!
I just found the files in Synaptics and installed them because software center wasn't finding them. Then I restarted my computer and now I can load any of my bookmarks within a couple seconds now! :) Is there a trial period I should lend to this? Or can I chalk it up as fixed permanently? And if I can consider it fixed, how do I mark this as solved for others to see?

Comment: I think it should be fixed permanently, the only times that your drivers may suddenly stop working is when you update your kernel (which generally happens only when upgrading to another Ubuntu version, say from 12.04 to 12.10). By the way, I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: Problem is not solved, though it's not as bad as it was. Just had to restart because my previous method of turning wi-fi off then on didn't work. It worked well for a while, any ideas why it's wtill happening?

Comment: Okay, I'm testing a wired connection and there seems to be the same problem with that as well...? This isn't making any sense anymore.

Comment: Does the Windows PC have any problem with the connection?

Comment: None at all, though ubuntu is faster at loading websites ;) It's only my comp that has any issues.

Comment: Ok..May you post or tell us what was your method of turning off WiFi (hardware switch, terminal code, etc)?

Comment: I have gnome shell installed; I simple use the top-right internet notifier to turn it off then back on after a few seconds. I must relay to you now though, that my internet was shut off due to financial circumstance and upon being turned on again, I've noticed a better connection. Though it's not fluid all the time as I've needed to turn wifi on and off a few times and restart twice so far, it gives me a stable connection for quite a while now. Perhaps there's a terminal code I can use to check if the packages I installed for the wlan-ng driver I installed are being used?

Comment: Not sure how to edit my previous comment, but I want to add that my wifi indicator is always between 4 and 5 bars, usually switching between them every few minutes. Not sure if it helps...

Comment: @Michael You can use the `lspci` command (to see if the hardware is recognized correctly), if you like, you can post it's output on [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and then share the link (so we don't overhaul the comments section). By the way, there's an 'Edit' link under each of your comments, but you can only edit them for the first 5 minutes (or so) since you wrote that comment. :)

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5702123/

Comment: And this is happening to me whenever I try to check for updates, gonna look up fixes for it now, but not sure if it'll help you figure it out or not..

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5702312/

Comment: @Michael, type this in a terminal `gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  C2518248EEA14886     
gpg -a --export C2518248EEA14886 | sudo apt-key add -`, then run `sudo apt-get update`. After that, you can install the packages you need.

Comment: I just unchecked all my PPAs that I added and did it, everything still installed properly. I can deal with that later, this internet thing needs to be resolved first I think. I use the internet almost daily for research and stuff.